# How do you take every row 70 after one row in a dataframe and add that row to the one row?

Tags: r, numbers, dataframe

If I have a row x in my dataframe, then I want to take the row (x+70) or 70 after x and add that row to the row x.

Here's an example:

```
     a b           a b a b
   x 2 3         x 2 3 4 5
   . . .
   . . .
x+70 4 5
```

Is there a way to do this for any number (not just 70) as well?

Edit: I forgot to mention this but I want to do this for all of the rows so that there are 70 rows in total.

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far?

Comment: I actually have not been able to make any progress at all on this problem.

Comment: and you are adding that 70th row as columns in first row, right?

Comment: im adding the 71st row as a column in the first row

Comment: @ user2654764:  What do you mean "you want to do this for all of the rows so that there are 70 rows in total?"

Comment: `do.call(cbind, split(DF, (seq_len(nrow(DF))-1) %/% 70))`

Answer (score 1):

A small example with a gap of 3 instead of 70, assuming that you are not interested in the last `gap` rows which will give `NA` in the 'new' a and b columns anyway.

```
dd <- data.frame(a = sample(1:10, 10), b = sample(1:10, 10))
dd
gap <- 3
cbind(head(dd, -gap), c(tail(dd, -gap)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following results in a one-row data frame, if the data frame is named `df` and `x` is numeric and row `x+70` exists:

```
cbind(df[x, ], df[x+70, ])
```

If you have to do this often or automatically, you would probably want to wrap it in a function to check whether row `x+70` exists.

Comment: I think that cbind combines columns not rows?

Comment: @Drew Steen, should it be `df[x+70, ]`?

Comment: @user2654764: Correct, `cbind` combines columns. The simulated output in your question has four columns starting with a data frame with two columns; that is what I have provided. @Henrik: Yep, thanks for catching my typo.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is what you are after, but if you want every 70th row you could use `seq`

```
df[seq(from=1, to=nrow(df), by=70), ]
```

where `df` is a dataframe. Instead of `from=1`, you could use any value `x`, and if you want a shorter cycle than 70 you can vary the `by` argument.

Comment: would this work if I wanted to combine them all together:for(i in 1:70){
df2 <- do.call(rbind,df[seq(from=i, to=nrow(df), by=70), ])
}

Comment: Actually, the command in the answer extracts all multiples of 70 at once. Hence there is no need for a loop/rbind, except if you are looking for 70 different subsets.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function `myrow` that allows you to input the dataframe, row number , and increment.

```
myrow<-function(df,x,y){
#df is my dataframe
#x is your row number
#y is the increment
#mydata is the desired dataframe

if (x>=nrow(df)){
cat("The value of x=",x, "is greater than number of rows of your dataframe=",nrow(df), "\n")
}else if ((x+y)>=nrow(df)){
cat("There is no row x+y=",x+y, "for this value of y=",y, "in your dataframe", "\n")
}else{
mydata<-cbind(df[x, ], df[x+y, ])
return(mydata)
}
}

#Testing the `myrow` function using the `mtcars` data in R

> myrow(mtcars,10,30)
There is no row x+y= 40 for this value of y= 30 in your dataframe 
> myrow(mtcars,34,10)
The value of x= 34 is greater than number of rows of your dataframe= 32 
> myrow(mtcars,2,10)
              mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear
Mazda RX4 Wag  21   6  160 110  3.9 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.07 17.4  0  0    3
              carb
Mazda RX4 Wag    3
```